# Promise allSettled running before promise finally

Tags: javascript, promise, fetch-api

I have a function that tries to load web images and tracks the count of loaded images and the count of the failed images. I am loading the images using `fetch` and using `Promise.allSettled` to run operations after all the images are validated.

```
const data = ["/test1.png", "/test2.png", "/test3.png"];
let imagesValidated = 0;
let imagesFailed = 0;
const promiseArr = [];

data.forEach((item) => {
  const imgPromise = fetch(item);
  promiseArr.push(imgPromise);

  imgPromise
    .then((resp) => {
      if (!resp.ok()) imagesFailed += 1;
    })
    .catch((error) => {
      imagesFailed += 1;
    })
    .finally(() => {
      // For the last image `test3.png`, the finally blocks runs after `allSettled`.
      imagesValidated += 1;
    });
});

Promise.allSettled(promiseArr).then(() => {
  // some operations
});
```

The issue I am facing is with the finally block. For the last image the finally block is running after the `allSettled` callback. This causes the `imagesValidated` to be lesser than the actual images scanned count. I do not want to remove the finally block as in the future I will be adding more cleanup code into it.

Is this the expected behavior of the Promise resolution methods? Is there a way I can fix this code without removing the finally block?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're pushing the `fetch` Promise to the array - not the chain that goes through `.then` and `.finally`. Push the whole chained Promise to the array.

```
data.forEach((item) => {
  promiseArr.push(
  fetch(item)
    .then((resp) => {
      if (!resp.ok()) imagesFailed += 1;
    })
    .catch((error) => {
      imagesFailed += 1;
    })
    .finally(() => {
      // For the last image `test3.png`, the finally blocks runs after `allSettled`.
      imagesValidated += 1;
    })
  );
});

Promise.allSettled(promiseArr).then(() => {
  // some operations
});
```

Or, even better, use `.map` on the original data instead.

```
Promise.allSettled(
  data.map(item => fetch(item)
    .then((resp) => {
      if (!resp.ok()) imagesFailed += 1;
    })
    .catch((error) => {
      imagesFailed += 1;
    })
    .finally(() => {
      // For the last image `test3.png`, the finally blocks runs after `allSettled`.
      imagesValidated += 1;
    })
)
  .then(() => {
    // some operations
  });
```

Though, note that using `Promise.allSettled` isn't helping you that much here - none of the Promises can reject due to the `.catch`. Consider either using `Promise.all`, or use `Promise.allSettled` with *just the `.fetch`*, so you can increment the counters after all responses have come back.